# Calling function inside object using bracket notation

Tags: javascript, object, notation

If i have a function defined inside some object as in :

```
var myobject={
myfunction:function(){//mycode here}
}
```

usually you can access the function using:

```
myobject.myfunction()
```

but what if i want to use

```
myobject["myfunction"]
```

trying so , actually the function did not get called , how can i call the function using brackets notation ?

Comment: Just a side note - Using bracket notation you can also have function names which are invalid otherwise. So `myobject["my  function"]()` will work but `myobject.my  function()` using dot notation will not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use it like. You were very close

```
myobject["myfunction"]();
```

You can also do this

```
var myfuncname="myfunction";
myobject[myfuncname]();
```

Answer (score 2):

The two forms

```
myobject.myfunction;
```

and

```
myobject["myfunction"];
```

are equivalent as long as you only use a fixed string to access the member (using a computed value is a different matter, then you must use the second form). Both lines result in the function-object-member `myfunction` which you can assign to a variable if you like, and calling that:

```
var myfunc = myobject.myfunction;
myfunc();
```

Note that assigning it to the variable breaks the `this` variable, so you might not want to do that if you're doing OOP.

And as you noted, calling a function means adding `()` with an argument list afterwards, it doesn't matter that the function is acquired through an expression, so either:

```
myobject.myfunction();
```

or

```
myobject["myfunction"]();
```